C# How to change XmlSerializer "cultureinfo settings"
I realize this same kind of question has been asked previously by some people. But solutions in those haven't really helped me.
My problem currently is that I have XML messages where for example double values are in format 4,5 using comma instead of dot. Changing the format isn't an option, because I can't control that.
The most obvious solution in my head first was to just change CultureInfo to the one I needed, but apparently XmlSerializer doesn't care about that in the slightest, even though some old solutions advice to change CultureInfo.CurrentCulture to tackle this problem.
XmlSerializer or XmlReader/Writer do not seem to have any support either to accept different separators.
Anyone have some good solutions to this without writing some conversion logic to classes that are being serialized/deserialized?

You could create a surrogate string property for each numeric property.  Or write some XSLT transformation to fix your numbers.  Or you could subclass XmlReader and fix your numbers as they are read.  But there is no direct way to do this with XmlSerializer because it is designed to support serialization and deserialization in conformance with W3C XML Schema Definition Language (XSD) which uses a period for its decimal point, with no localization.

See e.g. XML deserialization crashes on decimal parse due to formatting, .NET XmlSerializer and decimals, How to define the culture that the XmlSerializer uses (answer: you can't).

Adjusting to incorrect data is a vicious practice. The storage format is constant. The display format is variable. I would make an intermediate converter based on surrogate string properties as suggested above. But the basic business logic should not take into account such errors.

Thanks for the information guys. I have to come up with some other solution to this problem then.
